# Format numbers in table on pageload with jquery (or vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table with numbers and want the right formatting for every thousand, 1000 = 1,000.

I tried to do it in jquery.

My table

```
<td class="sorting_1">373432</td>
```

My jquery code that doesn't work

```
$(".sorting_1").ready.replaceWith(function(x){
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
});
```

My vanilla JS code:

```
var s1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sorting_1");
window.onload = function formatNumber(s1) {
  return s1.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');  
}
```

The output of the table should change from 373432 to 373,432

Comment: Internet tutorials, I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you got that ready syntax, but that appears to be wrong, and replaceWith is going to replace the element. You just need to swap the text.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".sorting_1").text(function(i, text){ 
    return Number(text).toLocaleString()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sorting_1">373432</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">12345</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">123456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Without jQuery

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sorting_1").forEach( function (td) {
    td.textContent = Number(td.textContent).toLocaleString();
  })
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sorting_1">373432</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">12345</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">123456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Better answer than mine by far.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! And thanks to Akin too! Appreciate it!

Comment: `$(".sorting_1, td:nth-child(2)")`